# USB keyboard with tracepoint but no touch pad?

Tags: keyboard

I've found [these keyboards](http://www.google.com/products?hl=en&q=usb+keyboard+with+trackpoint&um=1&ie=UTF-8&ei=IlZYTJujOpP0swPqpri1CQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&ved=0CBwQ_AU) but they all have touch pads and most of them mimic a laptop layout. Anyone know of a keyboard with a "trackpoint", no touch pad and a typical desktop layout (104-key)?

A little more hunting ("google: +104 + trackpoint) found the [trackpoint IV](http://www.clickykeyboards.com/index.cfm/fa/items.main/parentcat/16019/subcatid/0/id/189771) but I don't see any indication anyone makes them anymore.

And yet more digging, dug up this [Blog](http://www.pettijohn.com/2010/05/pointing-stick-usb-keyboard-roundup.html)... crud.

Answer (score 1):

Unicomp makes the '[Endura Pro](http://pckeyboards.stores.yahoo.net/en104wh.html)'. At a mere $99 it even includes buckling spring keys.

Comment: Unfortunate, I'm not a fan of buckling springs. :(

Comment: Let's see then...They make an integrated trackball with a rubber dome option (http://pckeyboards.stores.yahoo.net/ontheball.html). It looks like their Mighty Mouse used to have a trackpoint option, but doesn't anymore. You might try giving them a call.